# Making use of jquery-rails (ujs) when creating manual ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I implemented jQuery's draggable/droppable for a list of notes to order them hierarchically, which works fine at the moment, but I feel like I am doing too much.

The whole `csrf` part is sent manually with the request and I am also manually evaluating the response, which are features that ujs provides. Is there a way to integrate this seamlessly so that I can use the advantages of the ujs lib?

A possible solution I thought of would be to wrap the whole draggable into a `<form data-remote="true">` but that feels a bit hackish.

```
$(function()
{   
    $('#notes-container .note').draggable();

    $('#notes-container .note').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: ui.draggable.find('form').attr('action'),
                data: { 
                    authenticity_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),

                    task: { 
                        parent_id: $(this).data('id') 
                    } 
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Not that hackish at all,  you just have commit to AJAX for the entire form's processing.  I do it a lot.  I have forms with remote=>true with many tens of AJAX actions.  But beware,  I have a small set of users (like 277 MAX)  and I DON'T CARE that they MUST enable javascript to use my site.  I'm not the best to listen to if you're worried about being unobtrusive or worried about users with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: since this should be a little webapp, and I feel the web should evolve and not stand, I am not giving anything for users using e.g IE < 8 etc. My aim is to just keep the code clean and DRY, and not downwards-compatible for ten years ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the whole form that I need into the element, and then making the `draggable`/`droppable` callbacks fill in the values the form needs and firing the `.submit()` which then is handled by `jquery-rails`.